# How to test the jQuery UI slider widget with Selenium IDE?

Tags: jquery, selenium

We are using the [jQuery UI slider widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) in our web application and we want to automate testing of the UI with [selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/). We can't find a way to move the slider with selenium's commands. Can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the dragAndDrop command to move the slider. The following worked for me:

```
dragAndDrop | css=.ui-slider-handle | +100,0
```

This moves the slider 100 pixels to the right of its current position.

Comment: Warning implicit locators are deprecated, please change the locator to id=+100,0

Answer (score 2):

there is only one (*horrible*) solution for this. You will have to interact with the slider thought its jquery api.

selenium has a **runScript** method where you can pass some javascript to run. Do this only as your last resort though, as this will lead you down a slippery slope

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else has this problem and needs another perspective...

I had this problem a while ago and solved it by having the slider populate a hidden field and I used that as my interface with selenium IDE. I wasn't required to verify the slider worked at all so there was no need to test it. I just wanted the value of the slider.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several sliders, the command to move one of them is css=#id .ui-slider-handle

Thanks to Dave for the answer!