# Selenium Test to test Jquery Effects ( Slide, fade)

Tags: jquery-ui, selenium, automated-tests, jquery-effects

We have a web application and we are using JQuery UI transition effects fade and slide. We would like to automate this using selenium.

Does any one has any suggestion how can I achieve this goal ?

Thanks

Comment: I let you here [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357979/how-to-test-the-jquery-ui-slider-widget-with-selenium-ide) from a previous question related to this. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to invoke the effect/slide transitions from a test, so that you can test some other feature of your software, or do you mean that you think the transitions may be broken and you want to write tests that you could contribute to the JQuery UI project?

Answer (score 1):

**yes** man this is doable , for example :

to test JQuery `fade` you should first understand the logic for this method,
JQuery `fadeOut()` change the element display to `display: none;`

so you can get the element `display` value using `JavascriptExecutor` 
before runing jQuery `fade` and after ,
and check if the `display` value as you expected :

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $('#yourElementSelector').attr('style')");
```

note : change `#yourElementSelector` to your css selector 
and save the `Executor` into var so you can test the value like so