# How to dragAndDrop or move sliders with fluentlenium

Tags: selenium, playframework-2.0

I've seen that dragAndDrop can be used to move sliders with selenium like so:

[How to test the jQuery UI slider widget with Selenium IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357979/how-to-test-the-jquery-ui-slider-widget-with-selenium-ide)

But I have not found a way to do that in FluentLenium - the version which is used with PlayFramework 2.  Can this operation still be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My info may be a bit dated as it was almost a year since we tried to do tests covering drag'n'drop but at that point we had to use the selenium api directly (I think there is access to it from the fluentlenium wrappers). Sadly at that point we could not get it to work with any selenium driver.

This article refers to the API we tried to use: [How to automate drag & drop functionality using Selenium WebDriver Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210051/how-to-automate-drag-drop-functionality-using-selenium-web-driver)

Comment: Thanks. I think I saw how to access the API when googling around so I'll have to understand that a bit better. I'll accept the answer though!  (Not on this project at the moment though so unfortunately dont have any way to currently try it out)

Comment: @Codek Have you found a way to perform drag-and-drop with FluentLenium? If so, please share the details.